# Is it possible to use the ValidationPipe with whiteList on response body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs, class-validator

I'd like to prevent returning of object key values on responses of NestJs server (and using TypeOrm entity in the example)

For example, I'd like to make sure that a user's password will never be sent to any client:

user.entity.ts:

```js
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  password: string;
}
```

user.controller.ts:

```js
  @Get('')
  getAllUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
      return this.userService.getAll(); // expected: [{id: 1}], actual: [{id: 1, password: '1234'}]
  }
```

I that can be implemented for requests body by using class-validator pipe:

```
  new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true
  })
```

user.dto.ts:

```js
export class UserDto {
  @Allow()
  id: number;

  password: string;
}
```

Can that type of key's filtration possible with the `ValidationPipe`?
Is there any other elegant solution for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFIK `ValidationPipe` is there to validate **incoming** requests.

You should define a [serialization interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization) to proper remove the keys that you don't want to return. With this setup, you don't need to *validate* that DTO.

Comment: How do I validate the body of a response using class-validator in nestjs?